# bash: how to pass command line arguments containing special characters

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, special-characters

I've written myself a linux program `program` that needs a regular expression as input.

I want to call the program in the `bash` shell and pass that regular expression as a command line argument to the program (there are also other command line arguments). A typical regular expression looks like

```
[abc]\_[x|y]
```

Unfortunately the characters `[`, `]`, and `|` are special characters in `bash`. Thus, calling

```
program [abc]\_[x|y] anotheragument
```

doesn't work. Is there a way to pass the expression by using some sort of escape characters or quotation marks etc.?

(Calling `program "[abc]\_[x|y] anotheragument"` isn't working either, because it interprets the two arguments as one.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can either:

1. Escape each single special symbol with a backslash (as in `\[abc\]_\[x\|y\]`) or
2. Double-quote the entire argument (as in `"[abc]_[x|y]"`).

**EDIT:** As [some](https://superuser.com/questions/163515/bash-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-containing-special-characters#comment866278_163521) have pointed out, double-quoting does not prevent variable expansion nor command substitution. Therefore if your regex contains something that can be interpreted by bash as one of those, [use single quotes](https://superuser.com/questions/163515/bash-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-containing-special-characters#349036) instead.

Comment: In bash, double-quoting does **not** bypass expanding variables `"$HOME"` or parameters `"${USER:-root}"`, command substitution in either form `"$(date)"` or ``"`date`"``, arithmetic expansion `"$((1 + 2))"`, history expansion `"!!"` or backslash escaping `"\\"`. Use single quotes instead. See the man page of the bash manual, the section titled "Quoting".

Comment: Can also Use a file to get the args and in the commandline give path to file

Comment: Read [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) before just double quoting. It's one paragraph.

Answer (score 33):

Use single quotes. Single quotes ensure that none of the characters are interpreted.

```
$ printf %s 'spaces  are  not  interpreted away
neither are new lines
nor variable names $TESTING
nor square brackets [TESTING]
nor pipe characters or redirection symbols | > <
nor the semicolon ;
nor backslashes \a \b \c \\
the only thing that does not work is the single quote itself
'
```

There are two solutions if you need to embed a single quote:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '[ Don'"'"'t worry, be happy! ]'
[ Don't worry, be happy! ]
$ printf '%s\n' '[ Don'\''t worry, be happy! ]'
[ Don't worry, be happy! ]
```

Answer (score 9):

Per `man bash`

> There are three quoting mechanisms:
>   the *escape character*, single quotes,
>   and double quotes.
>
> A non-quoted backslash (**\**) is the
>   *escape character*.  It preserves the
>   literal value of the next character
>   that follows, with the exception of
>   <newline>.  If a **\**<newline> pair
>   appears, and the backslash is not 
>   itself  quoted, the **\**<newline> is 
>   treated  as a line continuation (that
>   is, it is removed from the input
>   stream and effectively ignored).
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes
>   preserves the literal value of each
>   character within the quotes.   A 
>   single quote may not occur between
>   single quotes, even when preceded by a
>   backslash.
>
> Enclosing  characters  in  double
>   quotes preserves the literal value of
>   all characters within the quotes, with
>   the exception of **$**, **`**, **\**, and, when
>   history expansion is enabled, **!**.  The
>   characters **$** and **`** retain  their 
>   special meaning  within double quotes.
>   The backslash retains its special
>   meaning only when followed by one of
>   the following characters: **$**, **`**, **"**,
>   **\**, or **<newline>**.  A double quote may
>   be quoted within double quotes by
>   preceding it  with a  backslash.   If
>   enabled, history expansion will be
>   performed unless an **!** appearing in
>   double quotes is escaped using a
>   backslash.  The backslash preceding
>   the **!** is not removed.
>
> The special parameters ***** and **@** have
>   special meaning when in double quotes
>   (see **PARAMETERS** below).
>
> Words of the form **$'***string***'** are
>   treated specially.  The word expands
>   to *string*, with backslash-escaped 
>   characters replaced as specified by
>   the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape
>   sequences, if present, are decoded as
>   follows:
>
> ```
>        \a     alert (bell)
>        \b     backspace
>        \e
>        \E     an escape character
>        \f     form feed
>        \n     new line
>        \r     carriage return
>        \t     horizontal tab
>        \v     vertical tab
>        \\     backslash
>        \'     single quote
>        \"     double quote
>        \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn
>               (one to three digits)
>        \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH
>               (one or two hex digits)
>        \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is
>               the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>        \UHHHHHHHH
>               the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is
>               the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
>        \cx    a control-x character
> ```
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted,
>   as if the dollar sign had not been
>   present.
>
> A  double-quoted  string preceded by a
>   dollar sign (**$"***string***"**) will cause the
>   string to be translated according to
>   the current locale.  If the current
>   locale is **C** or **POSIX**, the dollar sign
>   is ignored.  If the string is
>   translated and replaced, the
>   replacement is double-quoted.

Comment: This answer not only solves the problem, it solves also "why are you sure this will solve the problem" and "how did you learn about this solution". Thanks a lot!!!
It's actually quite difficult for people to read `man` page on certain topics especially when it's long and your 1st language is not English. Guess reading them through is still worthwhile!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a backslash ( `\` ) in front of special characters to escape them like so:

```
john@awesome:~ # echo \&
&
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it might not be useful as a regex, some character sequences may be interpreted as Bash variable names. To prevent this from occurring and avoid having them expanded, use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
program '[abc]_[x|y]' anotherargument
```

Quote each argument separately (if they need quoting) so they are interpreted as independent arguments. You can also use arrays in some cases:

```
param_array=('[abc]_[x|y]' anotherargument)    # create an array
param_array+=(yetanother)     # append another element to the array
program "${param_array[@]}"   # use the array elements as arguments to program
```

Answer (score 1):

```
program "[abc]_[x|y]"
program "[abc]_[x|y]" anotherargument
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping them should work fine:

```
  programm \[abc\]_\[x\|y\]
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the pattern come from?  Is it fixed or from a user?  Is it the user who is invoking the script on the local system, or someone remote?

You use quotes to wrap data to keep the shell from interpreting it.  There are two options:

1. Double-quotes, which still permit some interpretation ($expand and `backticks`)
2. Single-quotes, which pass everything through literally

Because `$` is a valid character in regexps (end-of-line/buffer) you probably want to use single-quotes to hold the regexp, unless you're storing in in a variable.  If you're taking arbitrary data from someone untrusted, you'll need to replace `'` with `'"'"'` and then wrap in single-quotes.

Note that `[abc]_[x|y]` looks like you want to match `x` or `y`, while it's actually matching one of the three characters `xy|`.  The square brackets match the characters within and only `-` for ranges and a `^` at the start for negation.  So, `[abc]_(x|y)` might be what you meant, and the parentheses are the characters which are special to shell.  Square-brackets are *not* special to shell, it just looks like they are.  Double-square brackets `[[ ... ]]` are special.

Comment: This is one of the most correct answers here (I appreciate especially the instruction for replacing `'` with `'"'"'`), however, it is still not correct. `[` IS a special character to shell, it is used in wildcards when doing path-expansion (which shell does for everything unquoted).

Comment: It's special in some contexts, such as variable subscripting or for globbing, but you can still type `foo=a[b]` and then `echo $foo` and see that the string did not need quoting. You're right, I was too brief.

Comment: If you are unlucky, there is a file `ab` in the current directory, and then `foo` will contain `ab` rather than `a[b]`. Quote your square brackets, people.

Comment: (For clarity: I do quote (as the original answer made clear, where I was pushing for quoting), and this is a side-derailment which I'm addressing). This assertion surprised me, so I tested it.  It's not true in zsh or bash, but is true in BSD /bin/sh.  This is against POSIX and is non-standard behavior, so you'll need to quote to handle it.  In zsh, you can `setopt glob_assign` to enable this behavior too, so quoting is the safest answer.